# Problem with Custom TFS Web Service Plugin

Tags: web-services, tfs

i'm not sure that what im going to do is the right so i first of all tell you my issue.
I have TFS as Bugtracking System and another system for tracking the worktime. I want that if a workitem status changes the other system changes the status too.

What i did until now is the following.

I wrote a plugin for the TFS web service were i catch the WorkItemChangedEvent.

```
 public EventNotificationStatus ProcessEvent(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, NotificationType notificationType, object notificationEventArgs, 
                                                    out int statusCode, out string 
statusMessage, out ExceptionPropertyCollection properties)   
        {
            statusCode = 0;
            properties = null;
            statusMessage = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (notificationType == NotificationType.Notification && notificationEventArgs is WorkItemChangedEvent)
                {
                    WorkItemChangedEvent ev = notificationEventArgs as WorkItemChangedEvent;
                    EventLog.WriteEntry("WorkItemChangedEventHandler", "WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " was modified");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return EventNotificationStatus.ActionPermitted;
        }
```

I droped the DLL in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2010\Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins
but i looks like the extension is never called. So nothing apears in the event log.

But if i try to debug the service like in this post http://geekswithblogs.net/jakob/archive/2010/10/27/devleoping-and-debugging-server-side-event-handlers-in-tfs-2010.aspx 
i cant hook on the process. So debugging does not work.
Why i cant debug the service? And is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To debug the w3wp.exe process, you need to be running Visual Studio as an administrator.

- From the menu, select **Debug** > **Attach to process** (or Ctrl-Alt-P)
- Select **Show processes from all users** and **Show processes in all sessions**.
- Find the w3wp.exe process that corresponds to your TFS Application Pool, and attach to it.

I notice that you're using EventLog.WriteEntry() - have you registered the event source previously in your code? To avoid the registration (which requires admin permissions), you might try using the TFS logger:

`TeamFoundationApplication.Log("WorkItem " + ev.WorkItemTitle + " was modified", 0, System.Diagnostics.EventLogEntryType.Information);`

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if you fixed this but to me it looks like you are missing the Subscription method in the class.

```
public Type[] SubscribedTypes()
{
    return new Type[1] {typeof(WorkItemChangedEvent)};
}
```

Without this your plugin will never get hit thus you will be unable to debug.