# TFS Server Side Plugin no longer works in 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I had created (modified an existing project) a server side plugin that has been working (on TFS 2012) for quite awhile.  When I upgraded the server to 2013, I copied the .dlls over to the same folder within the 2013 directory structure (Application Tier\Web Services\bin\Plugins), but it no longer works.

I installed remote debugging, attached my debugger to the w3wp.exe process (like here: [Problem with Custom TFS Web Service Plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992286/problem-with-custom-tfs-web-service-plugin)), and performed check-ins.  I'm pretty sure everything was in place because the first time I tried Visual Studio reported that symbols weren't loaded, but after copying up the .pdbs it looked 
good.  The ProcessEvent method never hit.

I can't find any new documentation on this stuff, guess this is just desperation, does anyone know what to do to make my plugin load?

Comment: You need to recompile the plugin an reference the 2013 binaries. The old binary will not load unless you do so.

Comment: And set project target to framework version 4.5 to get it to compile.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to recompile the plugin against the 2013 assemblies (there are tricks using binding redirects, but if you have the sources, please just recompile). And you need to set the .NET framework version to .NET 4.5 in order for the solution to compile (the TFS 2013 binaries target that framework version, so your plugin must target either 4.5 or higher in order to reference these assemblies).